# RecyclerView Item Click count

Tags: android, admob, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I am developing an android application using RecyclerView. I want to show admob interstitial ads for every 6 or 7 time user opens an Item. I want to count how many times user click on the item and if that count equals to 6 then i want to show the interstitial ad and then reset the count value to zero or else just carry on the normal process. I want to have some code example of how i can achieve this, any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Here is my sample onItemClickListener in recycler view adapter

```
OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DetailView.class);
        intent.putExtra(DetailView.PASSING_DATA, itemData.get(position));
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like something for `SharedPreferences`, a place to store a counter to get and update from anywhere in your app, that also retains its value even after your app closes.

Start here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm (includes full example)

snippet:

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("key", value);
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

insde the adapter class you should have the following code for handle the clicks:

```
  public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder          implements View.OnClickListener{
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtItemName;
        ArrayList<ListDataProvider> arrayList = new ArrayList<ListDataProvider>();
    Context context;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View view, Context context, ArrayList<ListDataProvider> arrayList){
        super(view);
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.context = context;
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_item);
        txtItemName= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
     }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     //handle the clicks here
     // to have the particular item do
     int position = getAdapterPosition(); 
     ListDataProvider listDataProvider = this.arrayList.get(position);
  }
}
```

you could add the shared preferences there like TWL said.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I found a way to do it.